# Cannot log in to apps or websites on iPad 1

Tags: ipad, safari, login

I haven't used my iPad 1 for a long time. Now I have reset it to factory default.

I can't use login features, e.g. Nextcloud via Safari or the Mixcloud app.
I type in my details and press login and nothing happens.

I have cookies enabled and JavaScript enabled. Everything worked in the past.

Comment: Is the date and time set correctly on the device?

Comment: yes, its set to autmatically and its correct.

if i type a wrong password, the msg appears "wrong password". very confusing...

Answer (score 1):

Try to enter to your iCloud account on another browser or laptop and look for your old iPad and try to reset it. Another thing that you can do is in Settings app look for your app store login problems.